# sbt refresh after changing build.sbt

Tags: sbt

Part of using and learning scala build tool involves making small changes to build.sbt and then rerunning sbt tasks.  But every time I change my build.sbt I need to restart the sbt console.  This isn't a huge deal, but it would be nice if there were an `sbt refresh` task or something that handled this.

Does anybody know how to refresh the sbt console after making a build.sbt change?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`sbt reload` does this.

Not sure why this wasn't immediately obvious.